# Oracle JSON_OBJECT omits leading zero when stringfied

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-ords

I'm using Oracle Rest Data Services (ORDS to communicate with some customers using the JSON format.
When I create a JSON_OBJECT and try to stringfy it, some numbers are not compliant to the ECMA-404 standard.

PLSQL Example:

```
PROCEDURE TEST_PROC(myJson OUT CLOB) IS
    myNumber NUMBER;
BEGIN
   jsonObject := new JSON_OBJECT_T();
   myNumber := 0.05;
   jsonObject.put("myNumberOutput", myNumber);
   myJson   := jsonObject.to_clob();
END PROCEDURE;
```

The final value of myJson (which is what I'm sending to my customer) is:

```
{"myNumberOutput" : .05}
```

What I expected:

```
{"myNumberOutput" : 0.05}
```

The weird part is that if instead of 0.05 I set myNumber with 0.5, the result I get from Oracle is:

```
{"myNumberOutput" : 0.5}
```

just like what I expected.

Does anyone have any ideia what I shoud do to get the json string with the number format and a leading zero when the number is less than 0.1 ?

Comment: Version of ords? Are you using auto PLSQL feature or did you write your own? Does SQLPlus demonstrate the same behavior?

Comment: Version 18.4  of ORDS... I wrote my own PLSQL, not using autorest feature.... but the problem happens before returning the json to the ORDS layer... in the ORDS I'm just using htp.prn(myJson) to return the JSON in the HTTP return... the problem is in the procedure itself...

Comment: since it's working for Connor - we can assume he's on 19 or 20c, which version of Oracle Database are you using? 12.1, 12.2, 18, 19?

Comment: Hi @thatjeffsmith .. version is 12.2.0.1.0   ... I think that is the problem, this bug has not been solved for version 12 yet

Comment: bug 27552855: JSON_OBJECT DOES NOT RETURN LEADING 0 FOR NUMBERS SMALLER THAN 0.1

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the code below on your system, because I can't reproduce

```
SQL> variable c clob
SQL> declare
  2      myNumber NUMBER;
  3      jsonObject JSON_OBJECT_T := JSON_OBJECT_T();
  4  BEGIN
  5     myNumber := 0.05;
  6     jsonObject.put('myNumberOutput', myNumber);
  7     :c   := jsonObject.to_clob();
  8  END;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print c

C
-----------------------------------------------------
{"myNumberOutput":0.05}
```

Comment: Hi Connor... I added an answer with the output... which version of Oracle is yours? I'm on 12.2 ... guess that's the difference :(

Answer (score 0):

@Connor, this is the result:

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> variable c clob
SQL> declare
  2         myNumber NUMBER;
  3         jsonObject JSON_OBJECT_T := JSON_OBJECT_T();
  4     BEGIN
  5        myNumber := 0.05;
  6        jsonObject.put('myNumberOutput', myNumber);
  7        :c   := jsonObject.to_clob();
  8     END;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print c

C
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"myNumberOutput":.05}
```